# How to disable interaction while ProgressView showing (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view with structure like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                // Several buttons and input forms
            }

            // the viewModel has published states. 
            switch viewModel.state {
                case .loading:
                    ProgressView()
                case .finish:
                    // ...
                case .error:
                    // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to simply avoid user interacting with any other components if the `ProgressView` appeared, but couldn't find a good way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.disabled` modifier on your controls.

For example:

```
Button("Button") { //action }.disabled(isLoading)
```

(You may want some sort convince property like this: `private var isLoading : Bool { viewModel.state == .loading }` )

In fact, because SwiftUI view modifiers like this will apply down to child views, you can apply it to a whole stack or group of controls:

```
VStack {
  //controls in here
}.disabled(isLoading)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Applying `.disabled` modifier to the whole Vstack works perfectly.  I defined a `==` function in the viewModel state enum so that `viewModel.state == .loading` could be passed to the modifier.